# C# .NET 2.0 Changing Google Chrome or Firefox Settings

Tags: c#, json, firefox, google-chrome, .net-2.0

i'm trying to do following with c#:

I want to read the Chrome or Firefox settings and edit some configurations (eg. Search Engine, Download Folder).

The problem is, i don't see how i can parse the settings from JSON in an loop-able data-structure, so i can loop through the array and change the settings i need and after that write it back in JSON.

has someone done anything similar and can help me?

This is a code snippet from my programm and how i do it now:

```
    ch_path = "path to Chrome settings";
    if (File.Exists(ch_path))
        {
            try
            {
                string[] ch_string = File.ReadAllLines(ch_path);

                    foreach (string ch_line in ch_string)
                        {

                            if (ch_line.Contains("homepage"))
                            {
                                    temp = "{\"homepage\": \"" + page_adress + "\",";
                                    new_ch_File.Append(temp + "\r\n");
                            }
                        }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why is an external application messing with peoples browser settings?

Comment: The "messing" is intentional and wanted. It's not a Virus or Trojan :D

Comment: And it's a c# Application with Admin, not a website.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're wording this wrong, I'm reasonably sure this would be a massive security issue. You won't be able to do this.

Comment: i am Able to do this but not very efficient. i can change it with replace but thats not rely what i want.

Answer (score 0):

I want to do it too as part of a desktop application with elevated permissions.  This is to file downloads by download date. Chrome/Chromium keeps user preferences in a JSON serialized settings file.  I don't see any Chromium API for this. The application does not pay attention to the JSON file; on exit it overwrites it. How do I get it to re-read the file or where is an API I can use in c#  / .net.  See question posed Jan 1.